# HTML / JavaScript File Selected Check

Tags: javascript, html, validation

So I can't figure out how to validate my form to make sure that their is a file being selected before the user can move on. I've seen some examples, but for some reason they only work in internet explorer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Here is my current HTML sheet:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Page</title>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["title"].value;
    if (x.length < 3) {
        alert("Title Needs To Be At Least 3 Characters Long");
        return false;
    }

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["lotsoftext"].value;
    if (y.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Caption Must Not Be Empty");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center><img src="Images/Drawing.png" onload="loadImage()" width="500" height="169"></center></h1>
    <center>
    <form name="myForm" action="Homepage.html" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="GET">

    Photo Title: <input type="text" name="title">
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
    <br><br><br>
    Caption: <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="lotsoftext"></textarea>
    <a class="btn" href="Homepage.html"></a>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>    
    <a href="Homepage.html">Cancel</a>
</center>
</body>
<script>
function loadImage() {
    alert("Image is loaded");
} 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have anything against using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add the `required` attribute to the file input, i.e.

`<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" required>`

Comment: @Jan Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank - You!

Answer (score 0):

When you upload something, the value of the `<input type="file" >` is a path to the uploaded file.

To check it, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">

<script>
    if (document.getElementsByName('upload')[0].value.length > 0) {
        //there is a path, so something is uploaded
    } else {
        alert('You have to upload something!')
    }
</script>
```

You can hook the if statement into were ever you do your form validation. This could also be used to make sure the file is a certain type, ie. a 'png' file or 'jpeg' file.

An example of what `document.getElementsByName('upload')[0].value` returns is: `C:\fakepath\randomimage.png`